# ES6 Generators and Object Destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

According to ES6, it is possible to use array destructuring returned from custom generators. Now however I couldn't figure a way to do the same with simple object destructuring as I thought this should work (using Babel and Polyfill):

```
class Test {
  constructor () { this.props = {a: 1, b: 2}; }

  *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* this.props; }
}

const {a, b} = new Test();
```

This should actually work no? Because it always simply returns undefined for a and b.

Comment: `function *gen() { for(i = 0, l = 10; i < l; i = i + 2) { yield i }} const [a, b, c, d, e] = gen(); console.log(a,b,c,d,e);` works as expected. `this.props` does not have a `Symbol.iterator` so passing through doesn't work like you're trying to do there.

Answer (score 1):

Array destructuring is tied to iterable/iterator objects. Object destructuring does not. If you want

```
const {a, b} = foo
```

to pull values for `a` and `b`, then `foo` needs to actually return a value for `foo.a` and `foo.b`. So you'd either want to just store the properties on the instance itself instead of `.props`, or use a getter like

```
get a() {
    return this.props.a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> According to ES6, it is possible to use array destructuring returned from custom generators.

Yes.

> This should actually work?

No - you were not using arrays here. By destructuring onto an object literal, the iterator was never invoked, and if it was it would have thrown an exception about the `this.props` object not being iterable.

Now however I couldn't figure a way to do the same with simple object destructuring as I thought this should work (using Babel and Polyfill):

```
class Test {
  constructor () {
    this.propA = 1;
    this.propB = 2;
    this.propArr = [];
  }
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    yield this.propA; // yield the single value
    yield this.propB; // yield another value
    yield* this.propArr; // yield every from an iterable
  }
}

const [a, b] = new Test();
//    ^    ^ *array* destructuring!
```

Object destructuring could be used here as

```
const {propA: a, propB: b} = new Test();
```

Comment: So basically its not possible to use object destructuring with custom generators? ;(

Comment: @AlexanderAdam Custom or not doesn't matter, object destructuring never invokes an iterator. Do you have an [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) with that? One could use a `Proxy` though